# The file “project.xcworkspace” could not be unlocked

Tags: xcode, appium

The file “project.xcworkspace” could not be unlocked. This issue is on 14.3

I am unable to change the permission

[image]

I opened the xcode then I received this popup. I have made the permission as well as read and write

[image]